# How add "completed work" field to task template in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I use TFS2012 using site https://myproject.visualstudio.com/

In task template I see only Remaining Work field, how can I add "Completed work" one?

Comment: What process template are you using? MSF Agile/Scrum?

Comment: agile, but it would be interesting to know how to do it in scrum too

Comment: I just created a new team project using Agile 6.1 and the is a "Completed" field on Tasks

Comment: hm.. yes - it's my fault, it was scrum actually

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible at the moment (there's another answer that links to blog post on how to add it yourself for older on-prem TFS, for VSTS and the Newer Work Item forms this should be possible to add via the web UI), see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/9c5c669d-2b4f-4450-aff1-a457d3279b39) on MSDN forums for details and it also cover's your question.

This paragraph explains the reasoning for leaving out original estimate and completed work:

> With the Scrum template we deliberately tried to keep to the minimum
>   set of fields that we thought were required to match the Scrum
>   methodology and make certain core TFS features operate correctly. We
>   always understood that there would be some customers who wanted to
>   capture additional information in the work items. In this case
>   customizing the work item types to match your needs was the expected
>   approach.
>
> I understand that currently you don't have this facility in the Hosted
>   TFS but hopefully we'll be able to address that in the future.
>
> On the question of analyzing the team's efficiency without adding
>   additional fields I have a couple of suggestions:
>
> 1.Utilize the Historical Query capability of Work Item Queries with an ASOF clause that allows you to query work items as they appeared at a
>   given point in time. This should be available to execute against
>   Hosted TFS team projects but does require you to run the query through
>   the TFS OM since there's currently no support for the ASOF clause in
>   the Visual Studio or Web Access clients.
>
> 2.For non-Hosted environments rich historical data is available in the TFS Warehouse and Analysis Services cube. I realize this currently
>   isn't available for the Hosted service, but it may help other users
>   looking for similar data.
>
> -Phil

Answer (score 0):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudiouk/2013/04/17/adding-completed-work-to-task-work-items-in-the-scrum-2-x-template-including-reporting/

follow steps in the url above

1 download tfs powertool

2 add fields (original estimate, completed word)